# can I use vinyl for floor protection

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, vinyl

Can I use a vinyl carpet like this:

https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/p.1000850316.html?eid=PS_GOOGLE_HD+%7C+PLAs_Shopping+%7C+Decor_Home+Decor&gclid=CJ6OhZirsdACFYZMDQodEEcAlw

to protect my hardwood floors?

I have a few use cases in mind:

1. Protect hardwood floor from kitchen sink water splashes (the sink is in the counter top that separates the kitchen from the dinning/living room)
2. Protect the floor from the computer chair.
3. Protect computer table from scratches.

So simply put, can I use a vinyl carpet on hardwood floors? Will it not leave stains? Will it not melt in the summer from direct sunlight or something? Is it practical in general?

Thanks

Comment: Most of the reviews are for use as a screen, 16 mills is not very thick I would think a office chair would make it curl up. I don't think it would melt but a non breathable membrane over the floor may cause a change in color.

Comment: A change in color?
What about regular floor protectors? They are not breathable too I think.
Are they safe to use?
Something like that: http://www.staples.ca/en/Staples-Hard-Floor-Chairmat-Rectangular-46-x-60-/product_715887_2-CA_1_20001